# Salary negotiation counter-offer

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

Do I send my job offer salary counter email to only HR, or should I cc everyone in the original offer email: SVP and president/ceo?

Comment: Is this an offer with your existing company or are you possibly moving on to a new one?

Comment: Since this was all occurring between the same company, I up-voted the best answer and deleted mine.

Answer (score 10):

Respond only to whoever sent you the offer letter. They will distribute it appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Negotiations should be private.

Copying others like a VP or the CEO could cause issues if the wording on your response isn't terrific. HR likely wouldn't care as much.

Discuss a counter-offer only with HR or your potential new manager. Do it over the phone if possible.

Answer (score 2):

**Original answer**

If HR copied everyone to the original offer, you should keep everyone in the loop.

You could also call HR directly to discuss the counter-offer before answering the email. Call HR, negociate on the counter-offer, and then send an email as a follow-up.

**EDIT : OP asked in a comment if he could avoid the phone part and stick with email.**

It is *OK* to respond by email. However, if you have a counteroffer, I believe you and HR will need to discuss, and this will lead to HR calling you. You can avoid being the one to call, but if the counteroffer is significantly different, expect problems communicating solely via email.

Additionally, you mention being *bad with the phone* because you cave in too easily. You are coming in this discussion with a big advantage : you can prepare because you have full information. HR will probably have to deal with the surprise, and you will have your arguments prepared. Even if phone calls are not your preference, you have optimal circumstances to lead the phone call successfully.

Comment: I am not good over the phone, I cave in too easily.  Is it ok to respond by email?

Comment: I'll edit the question, this comment answer might be long.